# Changes to MAMP's provided php.ini files doesn't lift the limits

Tags: php, mamp

I'm using MAMP with 5.6.13 as selected PHP version. I made changes to both php.ini files (increased upload_max_filesize) - in php.ini-development and php.ini-production accordingly. I shut off both Apache and MySQL servers and even restarted MAMP client itself. However, when I took a look at phpinfo(); page it stil displayed the same old limit.

I even tried making additional, new php.ini file but it didn't lead to any changes whatsoever.

What could cause this problem? Am I modifying the wrong files (C:\mamp\bin\php\php5.6.13 directory)?

Answer (score 0):

You may want edit the .htaccess file instead of doing it to your php.ini file. Most Wordpress installs are hosted on a shared environment and have no access to php.ini at all.

I have tried the same as you and have also tried to adding a php.ini into the wp-admin folder as well, but it didn't work. The code below works and not just on Wordpress sites but with all web applications that use PHP to upload.

Just copy and paste the code below to your .htaccess file:

(you will find it in htdocs > wordpress > .htaccess )

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M    
php_value post_max_size 50M    
php_value max_execution_time 500    
php_value max_input_time 500
```